# Cannot find module '...' or its corresponding type declarations. (NextJS + TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, next.js

- In my NextJs project, I have created **cookie.ts file in utils folder**.
- When I run "npm run dev" and when I check my application on localhost:300 it works fine, code from my file in utils/cookie.ts is fetched and everything seems ok without any errors.
- When I push my changes to gitlab then build fails with the error "**Cannot find module '../utils/cookies' or its corresponding type declarations.**"

Here is screenshot from gitlab:

[image]

Project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is fixed.

How I fixed it:

In my nextjs app, there is docker configuration included.

So I had to add this new folder (utils) to docker configuration.